# Issue in substituting string value in mysql insert statement python 3.7

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new in Python. I have written following piece of code to construct INSERT sql query:

```
sql = f"INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"

    params = []
    for k, v in my_dict.items():
        params.append(str(k), v) ##AS COL1 is of type varchar I am typecasting first param k

    for param in params:

        curr_sql_query = sql % param
        log.info(curr_sql_query)
        db_obj.execute(sql)
```

But even after converting first param to string as above, sql string I am getting as follows:

```
 INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (1.2.3.4, 1) where value should have been ('1.2.3.4', 1)
```

The error I am getting is as follows while trying to run the query string using `db_obj.execute(sql)` :

```
error=(1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.3.4 at line 1')"}
```

Answer (score 0):

`str(k)` does not add quotes(`'`). You should do it yourself.

```py
params.append((f"'{k}'", v))
```

If `k` is already `str` type, you can use `repr` that repesenting more detail for object,
`rerp('test')` returns `"'test'"` whereas `str('test')` returns`"test"`.

```py
params.append((repr(k), v))
```

But be careful with it, since if you already have `'` in `k`, it `repr` wraps your string with `"`.
For example,

```py
repr('\'Hello\' is string')
```

output:

```py
"'Hello' is string"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [placeholders](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html) instead to avoid issues with quotes, escaped characters and possible code injection:

```
sql = "INSERT INTO my_table (col1, col2) VALUES (%s, %s)"
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    db_obj.execute(sql, (str(k), v))
```